# Which statistical test to use in this case?

Tags: r, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

I’m working with a nassCDS dataset trying to solve a group of exercises of a task in R. In a previous step I create a new column (vehClassif) on the dataset from the continuous variable weight dividing into three categories (low, medium, high). But I’m stuck in this question:
For the continuous variable previously categorized in three groups, carry out statistical tests to determine if there is any other variable of the dataset varies depending on the group where the variable belongs to. If there are any differences among the categories indicate in which ones.

I don’t have any experience in statistics and I don’t know to what test the professor is referring to… I have read some literature about it and I’m guessing that the Chi-squared Test of Independence is what I need but I’m not sure, can anyone help.

Comment: How many variables do you have? What other variables are in the data set and of what kind?

Comment: Cases: 26217
Variables: 16

dvcat[factor]
weight[numeric]
dead[factor]
airbag[factor]
seatbelt[factor]
frontal[integer]
sex[factor]
ageOFocc[integer]
yearacc[integer]
yearVeh[integer]
abcat[factor]
occRole[factor]
deploy[integer]
injSeverity[integer]
caseid[character]